# Load cells in UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have UITableView with cells, i use footer(height = 10pt) for each sections, header (height = 64pt) for each sections and cell (hight = `self.view.frame.size.hight - 64 - 10`).

TableView loads only first cell, when i launch app (because second cell is not visible on screen), but i want to load first and next cell. And when i scroll to second row i want to load third cell.

How can i achieve this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`UITableView` delegate methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html) provide you several ways to track which cell just appeared on screen (i.e. `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:`).

One way to do it is to track which cell was displayed, and load +1 and/or -1 indexes manually.

**Note**: you shouldn't load the `UITableViewCells` directly but the content they are supposed to show (according to M.V.C).

Answer (score 0):

lazy-loading suit for you, which means first is visible, when scroll down second item should be ready.

//Store all items

```
NSArray *allItems = @[].mutableCopy;
```

//Load first two and store into allItems

```
NSDate *first, *second;
allItems = @[first,second];
```

//Check which cell is visible when scroll down and if the data has been ready

1) path.section is the visible cell

```
NSIndexPath *path = [tableView indexPathForCell:aCell];
```

2) allItems count is the number of data you have loaded

```
allItems.count = path.section + 1;
```

3) If `allItems.count == path.section`, you should load the next data, which is next of the current visible one.

By these two conditions the data should be ready all the time. 
After each load `[tableView reload]` to display.